Can I change an Acer Aspire 3 a315-41-r8th broken screen with a higher resolution one?
I have an Acer Aspire 3 with a broken screen which was a 1366x768.
I would like to use a 1920x1080 screen to replace the broken one; would I be able to?
Searching for my laptop's model number onlaptopscreen.com (I will be not using this site because I live in Europe) the 1366x768 screen and the 1920x1080 one seem to have the same connector and the screen I disassembled from my laptop seems to be the same one same one as well.
Photos of stickers if needed:
sticker on the bottom of laptop
sticker on the back of the disassembled screen

I bought a 1920x1080 replacement screen (ean:8053836254903) for the Acer Aspire 3 a315-41 SERIES and it worked without problems.
